# number of Instances of a custom class declared in a schema

Tags: rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I have an example of this data and its rdf schema:

[image]

and the schema

```
    #Dimension - row 
  :GeographicalRegion 
     rdfs:subClassOf scovo:Dimension;    
     dc:title "Police force area, English region and Wales". 
        
   #Dimensions - columns 
  :CriminalOffenceType rdf:type owl:Class ;      
    rdfs:subClassOf scovo:Dimension .
```

When they load the data and try to present it with this schema

```
:Cleveland rdf:type crime:GeographicalRegion;    dc:title "Cleveland". 
  # skippinf the declarations of instances  of the other regions... 

 :Criminaldamage rdf:type :CriminalOffenceType;      dc:title "Criminal damage".
 :Drugoffences rdf:type :CriminalOffenceType;        dc:title "Drug offences".
 :Criminaldamage rdf:type :CriminalOffenceType;      dc:title "Criminal damage".
 :Drugoffences rdf:type :CriminalOffenceType;        dc:title "Drug offences".
 # skipping the declarations of instances  of the other offence types...
```

And for example  after tha twe have

```
:ds1_27_10 rdf:type scovo:Item; 
     rdf:value **1,362;** 
     scovo:dataset :ds1; 
     **scovo:dimension :Drugoffences;** 
     scovo:dimension :Bedfordshire;  
     scovo:dimension :TP2008_09. 

:ds1_29_10 rdf:type scovo:Item; 
     rdf:value **4,766**; 
     scovo:dataset :ds1; 
     **scovo:dimension :Drugoffences;** 
     scovo:dimension :Essex;  
     scovo:dimension :TP2008_09.
```

SO the instances of this so called `CriminalOffenceType`  class each of them are created with the **same name** multiple times equal to the number of rows. The problem is I am not sure I understand why and will appreciate any help.  Why are we allowerd to use the same name for the instances?
And also I think the reason in the schema CriminalOffenceType is of  type  `owl:Class` is just for the reason that we prevent CriminalOffenceType to be used both as type and instance. Is that true?

Regards,
.

Comment: honestly, I don't understand what exactly you're doing - you missed the part mentioning how and with which tool you generate the RDF data out of the Excel sheet.

Comment: was done with Java but is not what  iam asking - what  Ido not understand is the schema and the why the rdf was constructed this way

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what you see as the issue. Expanding the shorthand notation with `;` you now have a triple `:ds1_27_10 scovo:dimension :Drugoffences` and another triple `:ds1_29_10 scovo:dimension :Drugoffences`. Is that not what you want, and if so, what do you want instead? Note that these are not "instances of the CriminalOffenceType class", it just denotes a (dimension) relation between the entity `ds1_27_10` and the entity `Drugoffences` and another dimension relation between `ds1_29_10` and `Drugoffences`.

Comment: Thank you I think it is starting to make sense. Ypou can see my attempt to model a simpel dataset in .rdf here in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76017242/modeling-dataset-in-rdf-format  and will be thankful to comment,